# Qual a forma mais adequada de testar o ERRORLEVEL em batch?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd

Já vi várias formas de teste do `ERRORLEVEL` em scripts batch. Algumas delas são perigosas e outras são erradas, mas às vezes passam despercebidas. Segue abaixo alguns exemplos que conheço:

> Perigoso: o teste funciona como "maior ou igual a 1", ignorando retornos negativos (usado em programas em "C"). Aqui não precisa se preocupar com a limitação de expansão em blocos.

```
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo Comando executado com problema
)
```

> Errado: o teste funciona como "maior ou igual a 0", indicando true para retorno com ou sem erro

```
if errorlevel 0 (
   echo Comando executado com sucesso
)
```

> Duvidoso: testa o resultado da execução de um comando ou batch com sucesso e erro, respectivamente. Essa forma é interessante, porém tem a questão da limitação de expansão em blocos IF/FOR, etc.

```
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
   echo Comando executado com sucesso
)

if not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
   echo Comando executado com problema
)
```

- Qual destas formas é mais adequada?
- Existe uma forma ainda melhor não citada?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provavelmente a última opção por conta da legibilidade e possibilitar lidar com retornos negativos.

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ( 
  echo OK
) ELSE ( 
  echo ERRO
)
```

Uma outra alternativa com [condicional](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html):

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo OK || echo ERRO
```

---

<sub>**Bônus**: Para especificar o retorno de uma subrotina, use [`exit /b [n]`](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html), onde `n` é o código de retorno.</sub>